# Getting wrong absolute value in C++/C

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to find the absolute value in C++ by the following method:

```
#include <cmath>
unsigned value1=4;
unsigned value2=10;

unsigned absoluteValue=abs(value1-value2);
int absValue=abs(value1-value2);

Answer: absoluteValue=4294967294
        absValue=-2147483648

Desired Answer=6
```

The value that I am getting for absoluteValue is 4294967294...which is wrong. The answer is also wrong for int. I need to compute the absolute value several times in code..is there a more efficient way to achieve this?

Is there an efficient way to find absolute value for integers?

Comment: Absolute value of an unsigned integer?

Comment: @devnull int is assumed when unsigned doesn't have a specific datatype following.

Comment: @juanchopanza I used http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp0x_online.php

Comment: Also, doesn't `abs` take floating point (float/double) arguments only?  So there's a number of implicit conversions going on here.

Comment: @Joe Is there an efficient way to find absolute value for integers

Comment: @juanchopanza I am on linux and my compiler is GCC. Its producing wrong result for me   see compileonline.com/compile_cpp0x_online.php . Thanks for replyinh

Comment: Well, first off, you should be using signed integers, not unsigned.  Then it's basically `(a-b)<0 ? -(a-b) : (a-b)`.

Comment: unsigned - unsigned is unsigned. absolute(unsigned) is pointless

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By subtract `unsigned` values like this, it might wrap.

If you want to get the absolute value of a `unsigned` do something like this:

```
unsigned absoluteValue = (value1>value2)?(value1-value2):(value2-value1);undeflow
```

Comment: The wording should be changed here. Technically, unsigned arithmetic does not overflow or “underflow”, because of the way it is defined. It wraps.

Comment: Yes, that term gets misappropriated for these cases.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Are `unsgined` guaranteed by the C++/C standard to wrap ? `int` is not, as I believe.

Comment: This answer is questionable - it is not modulo unsigned range

Comment: @KoKuToru "You can't subtract unsigned values like this, it might wrap" As you see he can! It is not an error.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I updated the answer, of course he can. But probably not what he wants..

Answer (score 1):

First of all in C++ such call is ambiguous. If you compiled the code in C then your result shall be equal to 6 in the both cases. The result you got can be get if you will cast the argument to double. For example

```
    absValue = std::abs( double( value1 -value2 ) );
    std::cout << "absoluteValue = " << absoluteValue << ", absValue = " << absValue << std::endl;
```

Compare two results of the function call in the following code snippet

```
    unsigned value1 = 4;
    unsigned value2 = 10;

    unsigned absoluteValue = std::abs( int( value1-value2 ) );
    int absValue = std::abs( int( value1 -value2 ) );
    std::cout << "absoluteValue = " << absoluteValue << ", absValue = " << absValue << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    absoluteValue = std::abs( double( value1-value2 ) );
    absValue = std::abs( double( value1 -value2 ) );
    std::cout << "absoluteValue = " << absoluteValue << ", absValue = " << absValue << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
```

The output will be

```
absoluteValue = 6, absValue = 6

absoluteValue = 4294967290, absValue = -2147483648
```

Why is there such a difference?

Expression value1 - valu2 has type unsigned int. Here is two-complement arithmetic. Then function abs is applied in the first case the expression is converted to signed int and will be equal to -6 according to the two-complement arithmetic. So function will return 6 for the both variable.

In the second case the (positive due to the type unsigned int) expression is converted to double and the function returns a double. It will be a positive value equal to 4294967290. Now this value for the second variable is converted to signed int and you get -2147483648

Answer (score 0):

`value1-value2` is in fact equal to 4294967294 in your C++ implementation, because `value1` and `value2` are unsigned and therefore modulo types.

Comment: So how do I find the absolute value of their subtraction. Thanks for replying

Comment: You did find the absolut value of the subtraction. The absolute value of 4294967294 is 4294967294.

Comment: I found the absolute value of subtraction only...see value1-value2. If this is not the correct method then can you please suggest one. Thanks again

Comment: To find the correct method, you have to specify desired functionality more precisely. You can use signed types to store the 4 and the 10, which will change the current behaviour to what I think is the one you expected for 4 and 10, but will introduce undefined behaviour for other cases than 4 and 10.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Well, first off, you should be using signed integers, not unsigned. Then it's basically</strike>

```
(a-b)<0 ? -(a-b) : (a-b)
```

e.g.

```
int main()
{
    int a=24;
    int b=10;

    unsigned ab=(a-b<0) ? -(a-b) : (a-b);

    printf("%lu\n", ab);
}
```

KoKuToru's answer does this right for unsigned.

Comment: Why should you restrict it to signed integers? The (unsigned) absolute difference is well defined for unsigned numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast these values to integer first.
Try:

```
#include <cmath>
unsigned value1=4;
unsigned value2=10;

unsigned absoluteValue=abs(static_cast<int>(value1)-static_cast<int>(value2));
int absValue=abs(static_cast<int>(value1)-static_cast<int>(value2));
```

Comment: This fails if the values aren't representable by `int`.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
unsigned int abs( int a )
 {
   if( a < 0 )
      return a * (-1);
   return a;
 }
```

Comment: Might as well call std lib `abs`, no?

Comment: No. std::abs returns -6 (I assume you know why), which turns out as 2^32 - 6 in unsigned, however, code above returns correct answers for the OPs example...

Answer (score 0):

Cast value1 and value2 to `long long`

take absolute value of difference

then cast answer back to unsigned - it will always fit